# Changing MySQL C# default date format when selecting Same like PHP

Tags: c#, php, mysql, datetime

I am aware that Datetime is saved in the database in this format : 2016-09-27 00:00:00 and I am happy with that as I am used to PHP.

However, in C#, when I select the datetime from database, and perform

`reader["date"].ToString()`

This is what I get:
`27/09/2016 12:00:00AM`

Is there any way to change the datetime format to `2016-09-27 00:00:00` ?

Beside of course using STR_DATE() on all my queries, which will be messy.

Regards.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Rather than read the date as a string, why not read it as a date using [reader.GetDateTime](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/html/M_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlDataReader_GetDateTime_1.htm) - then you can output or display it in any way you want.

Comment: I am using  reader.GetDateTime() now! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can use `ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")`

[Here you find more examples](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/)

```
reader["date"].ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```